I am trying to use return of concat() function as a argument for text() function, but it's just returning concat()
I have a problem when using nested functions in Excel. I want to display dates in a certain way (eg. "Monday, 15 April 2024"), so I have used text() for that. I also wanted to be able to change the language of the date, so I wrote this lambda function:
formatted_date = LAMBDA(date; locale; 
    TEXT(date;
        CONCAT(
            CHAR(34); 
            "[$-"; 
            locale; 
            "]dddd, d mmmm rrrr;@"; 
            CHAR(34)
        )
    )
)

Unfortunately, this is what this function is returning:[$-pl-PL]dddd, d mmmm rrrr;@
It's not giving me any errors.
When I put CONCAT() part in one cell, and TEXT() part in another cell with reference it's working just fine. But it's not optimal, is it?
This is not the first time I have a problem with nesting even two functions inside each other in Excel. I'm pretty new to this, and having some experience in programming it's just bizarre that such easy tasks are that hard.
Please, would anyone give me a hint how to overcome this without using extra cell for every step of the calculation?
Thank you very much.

is the closing ) for the concat in the right place?

Remove both CHAR(34). Also note that TEXT() is a nasty useless function that always interprets the format text in the language of the Excel that runs it, and the [$-pl-PL] does not change that. So the dddd, d mmmm etc will work only when the Excel language is such that those letters represent "days" and "months", such as in English. It's impossible to make portable files with it, hence my assessment of its usefulness.

@GSerg as always, it's working on mine machine :D

@GSerg "and the [$-pl-PL] does not change that" That is not the case for my US-English Excel 365. The LCID can be used in the same way as in the number format dialog. One does have to use the local date-part tokens, and that can be an issue. But a Workbook Open macro can take care of that, if necessary.

@RonRosenfeld The local date-part tokens is all I was talking about, otherwise you will get a Polish resulting string of course. How does workbook open affect it though?

@GSerg See my accepted answer here for a method that allows the TEXT function to use the proper tokens.

You don't need the CHR(34). This works here (US English based Excel, so separators and year token are different)
=LAMBDA(date,locale,TEXT(date,CONCAT("[$-",locale,"]dddd, d mmmm yyyy;@")))

Using:  =formatted_date(A2,B2)

